# Create multiple instances of the same process with multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to make a program where the main process handles all incoming connections and then hands them off to different processes to host the server. But I have run into an issue, I do not believe I can use pool to do this. Here is my code:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def startserver():
    print("hi")
if __name__ == '__main__':
    mp.set_start_method('spawn')
    process = []
    command = 1
    i = 0
    while True:
        if command == 1:
            process[i] = mp.Process(target = startserver)
            process[i].start()
            i += 1
            if i == 10:
                break
```

But when i do this all i get is the error:

```
 File "server.py", line 12, in <module>
 process[i] = multiprocessing.Process(target = startserver)
 IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the issue? What's your question?

Comment: You can't add elements to a list that way. you need to use `process.append()`. Don't take this the wrong way but I would tackle the very basics of python before jumping into multithreading. You'll have a very frustrating time otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your list is empty after string `process = []` but you try to access an existing (really not exisiting yet) element of this list (`process[i] = ...`). Try to use `process.append(mp.Process(target = startserver))` or something identical.